# Check which users have specific password

Tags: users, password

I'm trying to remove all default user passwords across a bunch of servers with `ansible`. Firstly, I'd like to output the name of every user whose current password is `foobar`. How can I achieve this?

My first intent was to get the hash from `/etc/shadow` and `grep` for it, but this won't work because of salting.

Do I need to calculate my own hashes for this and compare them? Or is there a faster and easier approach?

Comment: The reason why password hashes are saluted is to prevent this exact search.  This is supposed to be difficult.  Any solution will require re-hashing guesses (like `foobar`) for every users.

Answer (score 5):

There's a specialized tool for password weakness check: [John the Ripper](https://www.openwall.com/john/) available and probably packaged in all common Unix & Linux flavours.

Here's an example of usage on Debian GNU/Linux 9 ([*unshadow*](https://manpages.debian.org/john/unshadow.8) comes along [*john*](https://manpages.debian.org/john/john.8)). Some care should be taken when manipulating password files, this is just a PoC. Note that the *john* command could be run remotely (and thus not installed anywhere else than a dedicated system) as long as it's provided suitable password files.

Setup (including setting password *foobar* to account *test*):

```
# echo test:foobar | chpasswd
# grep ^test: /etc/shadow
test:$6$84SIejUB$qM5UulJEIiwjOc4PWXYupWoyU/jMP0rKA8cM1g8CEOgxMlC.x4ndbbdRq438rjKb.6UwCoTqzvgxoi0h51Kpm1:18050:0:99999:7:::
# unshadow /etc/passwd /etc/shadow > /root/workpasswd
# echo foobar > /tmp/wordlist
```

Test for forbidden/default passwords:

```
# john -wordlist:/tmp/wordlist /root/workpasswd
Created directory: /root/.john
Loaded 3 password hashes with 3 different salts (crypt, generic crypt(3) [?/64])
Press 'q' or Ctrl-C to abort, almost any other key for status
foobar           (test)
1g 0:00:00:00 100% 5.882g/s 5.882p/s 17.64c/s 17.64C/s foobar
Use the "--show" option to display all of the cracked passwords reliably
Session completed
```

Result:

```
# john -show /root/workpasswd 
test:foobar:1001:1001:,,,:/home/test:/bin/bash

1 password hash cracked, 2 left
```

Cleanup:

```
# rm -r /root/workpasswd /root/.john /tmp/wordlist
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you try logging in as each user? e.g.

```
echo "foobar" | su username
```

You would need to temporarily [disable the TTY check](https://superuser.com/questions/119376).

Answer (score 2):

So here is a little C snippet that checks for the existing users password:

Save the following snippet in a file called: `checkpass.c`

```c
#include <pwd.h>
#include <shadow.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <crypt.h>

static int pwcheck (char *user, char *passwd)
{
    struct passwd *pw;
    struct spwd *spwd;
    char *epasswd, *cpasswd;
    char *tty;

    if ((pw = getpwnam(user)) == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
     /*
     * XXX If no passwd, let them login without one.
     */
    if (pw->pw_passwd[0] == '\0') {
        return 0;
    }
    spwd = getspnam(user);
    cpasswd = (spwd ? spwd->sp_pwdp : pw->pw_passwd);

    epasswd = crypt(passwd, cpasswd);
    if (epasswd == NULL) {
        return 2;
    }
    if (strcmp (epasswd, cpasswd)) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3) return 4;
    return pwcheck (argv[1], argv[2]);
}
```

Compile the above code using:

```
gcc -o checkpass checkpass.c -lcrypt
```

Now from the command line just run the following:

```sh
while IFS=: read -r user _; do
  if ./checkpass "$user" foobar; then
    printf 'The ollowing user %s has the password set to foobar\n' "$user";
  fi;
done </etc/passwd
```

It's maybe a long shot but should work!

Answer (score 1):

Because I'm not a fan of installing extra software and don't want to mess around with `sudoers`, what I ended up doing was

```
sshpass -p foobar ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=keyboard-interactive,password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no user@host
```

and afterwards check the exit code in Ansible. If the password was correct the exit code will be 0, otherwise 5.

This will obviously only work if password authentication is allowed in your SSH server config.